# Is there a command line calendar calculator?

Tags: linux, command-line, unix, bsd

Is there a command line calendar calculation which provides these features?

- Date (plus|minus) date interval calculation
- User specified input and output format

Comment: Use any programming language?  Python is nice.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `date` command will do much of this for you.

For example, November 1 plus 3 weeks is `date -j  -v+3w -f"%m/%d/%y" "11/01/10"`

Here are some examples from the man page:

The command:

```
 date "+DATE: %Y-%m-%d%nTIME: %H:%M:%S"
```

will display:

```
 DATE: 1987-11-21
 TIME: 13:36:16
```

In the Europe/London timezone, the command:

```
 date -v1m -v+1y
```

will display:

```
 Sun Jan  4 04:15:24 GMT 1998
```

where it is currently Mon Aug  4 04:15:24 BST 1997.

The command:

```
 date -v1d -v3m -v0y -v-1d
```

will display the last day of February in the year 2000:

```
 Tue Feb 29 03:18:00 GMT 2000
```

So will do the command:

```
 date -v30d -v3m -v0y -v-1m
```

because there is no such date as the 30th of February.

The command:

```
 date -v1d -v+1m -v-1d -v-fri
```

will display the last Friday of the month:

```
 Fri Aug 29 04:31:11 BST 1997
```

where it is currently Mon Aug  4 04:31:11 BST 1997.

The command:

```
 date 0613162785
```

sets the date to ``June 13, 1985, 4:27 PM''.

```
 date "+%m%d%H%M%Y.%S"
```

may be used on one machine to print out the date suitable for setting on another.

The command:

```
 date 1432
```

sets the time to 2:32 PM, without modifying the date.

Finally the command:

```
 date -j -f "%a %b %d %T %Z %Y" "`date`" "+%s"
```

can be used to parse the output from date and express it in Epoch time.

Comment: I think your examples are mostly for BSD `date` only. The `-v` option isn't available with GNU date (for version 8.5 at least).

Comment: Good point. GNU date has the --date option and a different syntax.

Answer (score 4):

Like Zoredache says, you can easily achieve it using any scripting programming language.

Here is an example in Ruby

```
 > irb
 1.9.3-p286 :001 > require 'date'
  => true
 1.9.3-p286 :014 > Date.new(2012,11,1) - Date.new(2012,1,2)                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
  => (304/1) 
 1.9.3-p286 :015 > Date.new(2012,11,1) + 10
  => #<Date: 2012-11-11 ((2456243j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)> 
 1.9.3-p286 :016 > Date.new(2012,11,1) - 205
  => #<Date: 2012-04-10 ((2456028j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```

Answer (score 4):

As for custom input and output formats, check out [dateutils](http://www.fresse.org/dateutils/).  It provides the `dadd` command to do the Date (plus|minus) date interval calculation:

```
$ dadd -i '%B %d %Y' 'November 1 2012' +3w
2012-11-22
$ dadd 2012-11-22 -3w -f '%B %d %Y'
November 01 2012
```

The `-i|--input-format` option works throughout all tools and supports most of `strptime(3)` specifiers.  Same for the `-f|--format` option.

Disclaimer: I am the author of the toolset.